# uploading files directly to a web page

Tags: upload, photos

would like to allow visitors to a web page to upload photos that will post right onto the page. i have the script that will allow them to browse their files and choose the files, but don't know how to get them to "submit". help?

Comment: Show us the form code and the server side code and we will help you.

Comment: i'd like to do it with a simple javascript if possible. i'm using a free web site (webs.com). the code to attach the files is: <form id="imgForm" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <p><label for="img0"><input type="file" id="img0" name="img0"/></label></p> </form>

Comment: @John: If you wanna upload image to server then only JavaScript will not work.

Comment: ok, what can i do, or use, then?

Comment: @John: Check my answer. may be it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `servlet`. Here is an tutorial for that: [upload-image](http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/upload-image.shtml)

Hope this helps.

Comment: this looks like it may just do the trick! thank you! i'll try it out and let you know for sure!

Comment: ok, i'm a little confused. what exactly do i put into the source code for the page? just the .jsp code? and will this post the images directly onto the page automatically?

Comment: @John: Where you get stuck? Elaborate a little more?

Comment: hi harry. i'm trying to make it so that a visitor to thepage can post their pic(s) to the page, without my intervention. in the example, there are 2 sections. Source Code of uploadImage.jsp & Source Code of UploadImage.java. what do i add to the html code for the page? just the .jsp code? and will this post the images directly onto the page automatically?

Comment: @John: The jsp page is the view of the page.Its a simple html page. And the java file is servlet and contains logic of uploading image. To post image to java file you defined it in `action` property of `form` tag in jsp/html.